# How does the electromagnetic field of an electron and a rotating ball of charge behave in a co-rotating reference frame?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, quantum-spin

First time poster, hope I'm not breaking any rules.

Basically I'm curious about how far the classical analogy of an electron as a rotating ball of charge can be stretched.

The situation I'm imagining is looking down the axis of the ball. At rest you see an electric field due to the charge of the ball and a magnetic field pointing at you due to its rotation. If you begin rotating at the same rate as the ball, you will no longer see any current. This would ordinarily imply no magnetic field, but I'm not sure if Maxwell's equations would even hold in a rotating frame (since its non-inertial).

Whatever the answer, I'm curious whether it would be the same for an electron. Since it isn't really rotating, and its magnetic moment is not as well-defined, I'm not sure what to expect.

Comment: This seems to be a calculation of electromagnetic equations, etc. in rotating frames: http://puhep1.princeton.edu/~kirkmcd/examples/rotatingEM.pdf Maybe it's useful...